# Laravel belongsToMany save does not respect primary key

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, geonames

I have self-relating table:

```
    Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('geoname')->unique();
        $table->enum('type', ['continent', 'region', 'country', 'state', 'city'])->index();
        $table->string('code', 2)->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('language', 2)->nullable()->index();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('population')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unique(['code', 'type']);
    });

    Schema::create('regions_has_regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('region_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('has_region_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('region_id')->references('geoname')->on('regions');
        $table->foreign('has_region_id')->references('geoname')->on('regions');
    });
```

I want to use `geoname` as primary key (as it is a globally unique integer identifier)

Model has:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'geoname';

public function children(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Region::class,
        'regions_has_regions',
        'region_id',
        'has_region_id',
        'geoname',
        'geoname',
        'children');
}

public function parents(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Region::class,
        'regions_has_regions',
        'has_region_id',
        'region_id',
        'geoname',
        'geoname',
        'parents');
}
```

Primary and relation keys are set to `geoname`.

But here I import countries in continents:

```
    foreach ($continents as $continent) {
        $pop = 0;
        $continent->children()->saveMany(
            collect($earth->find(['continent' => $continent->code])->useShortNames()->toArray())
                ->map(function ($c) use ($continent, $now, &$pop) {
                    $pop += $c['population'];
                    return Region::create([
                        'code' => $c['isoCode'],
                        'name' => $c['name'],
                        'type' => 'country',
                        'language' => $c['language'],
                        'population' => $c['population'],
                        'geoname' => $c['geonamesCode'],
                    ]);
                })
        );
        $continent->update(['population' => $pop]);
    }
```

And get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`regions_has_regions`, CONSTRAINT `regions_has_regions_has_region_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`has_region_id`) REFERENCES `regions` (`geoname`)) (SQL: insert into `regions_has_regions` (`has_region_id`, `region_id`) values (7, 6255146))
```

As you can see it tries to insert `id` value to `has_region_id`, instead of `geoname`.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out: Model should have this:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```